# Is it possible to prevent imported javascript code from modifying my dom

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

What I want to do is to allow other people to be able code their own logic to render contents of certain div element I give them. It is a space they can freely add DOM elements, customize with their own CSS, and design however they want it to look like.

However when I do that I run into the problem with CSS conflicts and Javascript global variable conflicts. I came across shadow DOM and would this be the right technology to use for this use case? If so, how do you prevent others from selecting DOM elements outside of their shadow DOM? For example if they do something like $('body') using jquery and start changing it.

Also another thing to consider is what people will be rendering inside this given div element relies on getting data from my web application. A good example might be a stream of data and some unknown type of chart they may be designed by others to display realtime data.

Comment: making the space an iframe must do the trick

Comment: Could you elaborate, what and how the users build inside the `<div>`? To give the users access to some data, you can allow your users to create a websocket connection or REST request to your webserver. If you however want to create a connection between your site and the iframe with JavaScript, you do not have many options. The only possibility I see here is to add some params to the iframe link, e.g. `src="index.html?param1=value1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `iframe` sandbox. You have several options to disallow scripts or let the page behave like it is on another domain. You can find all the options here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

An example for your use case would be:
`<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="anotherpage.html"></iframe>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot to mention something in my problem so I added it above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an `iframe` with the `sandbox` attribute, the sort answer is **NO**. It's not possible.

JavaScript runs inside a window and has complete access over the document in the window. You can try to modify some functions, but there is no way of doing it the right way.

Just use an iframe for this.